# Single Charge With StripeJS using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I absolutely cannot find anything online to help me integrate stripe with Laravel 5.2.  It's been challenging to learn this framework because of so many deprecations between versions :(

Anyway, here's what I'm working with

JS file to capture input

```
$(function() {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');
  $form.submit(function(event) {
    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
    $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

    // Request a token from Stripe:
    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from being submitted:
    return false;
  });
});
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  // Grab the form:
  var $form = $('#payment-form');
  var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

  if (response.error) { // Problem!

    // Show the errors on the form:
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

  } else { // Token was created!

    // Get the token ID:
    var token = response.id;
    console.log(token);
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));

    // Submit the form:
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

once the form is done, I route the user to `{{ route('success') }}` via the `action=""` attribute in the form.

```
Route::any('/success', ['as' => 'success', 'uses' =>'ChargeController@pay']);
```

here is my controller with code provided by stripe...as you can see it will not work

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateSongRequest;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Billable;
use Input;

class ChargeController extends Controller
{
    public function pay(Request $request){
        if(Input::has('stripeToken')){
            $token = Input::get('stripeToken');
            $amount = 10;
// I cannot use this part even though it is in the stripe documentation
            $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
                                'card' => $token
                            ));
            $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                        'customer' => $customer->id,
                        'amount' => ($amount*100),
                        'currency' => 'usd',
                        'description' => "test"
                    ));
            echo 'success!';
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking at using the [StripeJS documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) instead of cashier.
Currently, I'm looking at this error

`Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Stripe_Customer' not found`

And that's where the documentation ends. Any help? I would prefer to use cashier, but I can't find any documentation for "non-subscription" based use and the laravel website is not much help.

Comment: do you have a Stripe_Customer class?

Comment: That error is looking for a controller, does Stripe_Controller exist in that location?

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja the class doesn't exist because there are no tutorials to tell me what to put in there. the StripeJS docs stop there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kevin's answer is fine, anyway if you are still intrested on what is wrong with your code

here is the solution

Try this code in the controller

First of all you need to add this package

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

Then try

```
class ChargeController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(){
     \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249');
    }

    public function pay(Request $request){
        if(Input::has('stripeToken')){
            $token = Input::get('stripeToken');
            $amount = 10;

            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                        'customer' => $customer->id,
                        'amount' => ($amount*100),
                        'currency' => 'usd',
                        'description' => "test",
                        'card' => $token
                    ));
            echo 'charged successfuly!';
        }
    }
}
```

if this throws an error related to customer id, you can create the customer first then charge

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using Cashier. In your composer require:

```
"laravel/cashier": "~6.0"
```

You'll need to add to the providers in your config/app.php as well:

```
Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class
```

Under config/services add your Stripe API keys and that's about it for setup. To use stripe for a single product purchase simply integrate the Stripe Purchase button:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/checkout')) !!}
  {!! Form::hidden('product_id', $product->id) !!}
  <script
     src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
     data-key="{{env('STRIPE_API_PUBLIC')}}"
     data-name="your app"
     data-billingAddress=true
     data-shippingAddress=true
     data-label="Buy ${{ $product->price }}"
     data-description="{{ $product->name }}"
     data-amount="{{ $product->priceToCents() }}">
   </script>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Alternatively you could integrate a cart and pass the entire purchase to stripe from there, but that is slightly more involved. I highly recommend this, it helped me figure it all out for my shop: https://leanpub.com/easyecommerce

Once from the form route, you pass to a controller method where you grab the request:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{ ....
```

You could var_dump to see the various data that the stripe button passes.

Comment: But how do you "charge" the card on the backend? From what I understand with this method is that it generates a token, but you need to do something with it

Comment: I figured it out. The `/checkout` page must contain the PHP code from here https://stripe.com/docs/charges

Comment: Yes they process on their end but you can also grab all that data in your controller as a request

Comment: if you update your answer with the solution, I can give you a green checkmark :)

Comment: @MarkusProctor I added the way to get the form data on the laravel side, beyond that I'm not sure what else you need to be shown. This breaks it all down.